# SQL INSERT code troubleshoot

Tags: sql, insert

I am trying to run this code but am receiving a Compile Error - Expected end of statement on the INSERT....line.

What could be wrong?

```
Private Sub cmdInbound_Transport_Click()

Dim iProduct As Integer

iProductID = DLookup("DefaultProductID", "tblProductType", "ProductTypeID" = 1)

INSERT INTO tblGuestProduct (ProductID, GuestID,) VALUES (iProductID,tblBooking!subGuest.GuestID);

End Sub
```

Comment: which language vb ?? check the comma after guest id.. & if vb it should be in quotes..

Comment: Removed the comma after GuestID but that did no good. Still getting the same error. BTW it is VBA and am running it in access 2010

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra comma in your Insert statement. Try this,

```
   INSERT INTO tblGuestProduct (ProductID, GuestID) 
   VALUES (iProductID,tblBooking!subGuest.GuestID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete comma (near `GuestID`). Insert line should be like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblGuestProduct (ProductID, GuestID) VALUES (iProductID,tblBooking!subGuest.GuestID);
```

Full code:

```
Private Sub cmdInbound_Transport_Click()

Dim iProduct As Integer

iProductID = DLookup("DefaultProductID", "tblProductType", "ProductTypeID" = 1)

INSERT INTO tblGuestProduct (ProductID, GuestID) VALUES (iProductID,tblBooking!subGuest.GuestID);

End Sub
```

Comment: Or perhaps the problem is with the Dlookup. If it enter ? DLookup("[DefaultProductID]", "tblProductType", "[ProductTypeID] = 1") into the Immediate window I get an answer. But if I enter ? iProductID into the immediate window nothing is returned.